# Cumulative bivariate normal

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

How do I calculate the cumulative probability distribution function for a bivariate normal distribution with conditions $P( x>a , y>b)$?

Is there any method to solve
$$P(x>a,y>b)\\\int_{b}^{\infty}\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left(-\frac12\frac{x^2-2\rho xy+y^2}{1-\rho^2}\right)\,dx\,dy$$

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/C2ayp.jpg

Comment: I suppose you are after numerical stuff, isn't it?

Comment: In the [R package mvtnorm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/), there is the `pmvnorm` function.  Or you could read some papers by [Alan Genz](http://www.sci.wsu.edu/math/faculty/genz/homepage)

Comment: I read papers by Alan Genz but were too complex for understanding. :( Does pmvnorm calculate the cdf or pdf ?

Comment: I need to prepare a macro in excel or a code in R or Cpp, which calculates the CDF that is numerically equal to the given the integral.

Comment: @amanized: `pmvnorm` calculates the CDF (see pages 6-8 of the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/mvtnorm.pdf), and note that the default algorithm uses Monte-Carlo simulation, so may give slightly different values each time it is run) and allows you to specify the limits of integration.  If you want the density, try `dmvnorm` in the same package